# Truncate neither Delete * FROM table dont work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, truncate

short question I cannot TRUNCATE nor DELETE * FROM table in PHP code.
In MySQL it works like charm, but I am getting crazy why it doesnt work in code when I have two same tables and codes and one works and second doesnt.

```
PHP///DELETE TEMP TABLE

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "xxx", "db_test");
$truncate_table = "TRUNCATE TABLE temp_table;";
$delete = mysqli_query($link, $truncate_table);

////MYSQL
CREATE TABLE `temp_table` 
(
    `ID` INT(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
    `task_number` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '0',   
    `type` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `assign_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `team` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `task` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `comment` TEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

I tried: 1. change quotes, change form of mysql query, use delete * from, remove and recreate table, nothing,

Also no error is shown in echo but as I said in MySQL the command is successfull.

Comment: try query like : $truncate_table = "TRUNCATE TABLE temp_table"; remove ; from inside the query

Comment: Here you go, now you can make errors shown.

Comment: Suyash - didnt help :(

Comment: @YourCommonSense as I said no error showed.

Comment: if there is no error, then your table has been truncated succesfully

Comment: SOLVED ! or die($link) showed error:
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

So I closed query before and then reopened the connection.
Problem solved.

Comment: this is a rather barbaric way of solving errors.

Comment: I am sorry I am not professional programmer, if it runs then its all okay